# notepad++ : How to replace one line of text with another

Tags: notepad++

I have records in notepadd++ in this below format

> 611090102932 20161130         12563 20170112 100333IMPAYES   STASIE     2017 01 12       5640 00000000ESPECE

i have 190 lines of data like this. So i want to replace the 5640(number) that is before 00000000ESPECE with 12563(number) that is before 20170112 for all the lines in the file.

I tried installing ToolBucket plugin but i am not sure how do i select the line i want and replace it with the other one

i would appreciate if someone could help me

Comment: So, `20170112` and `00000000ESPECE` are static and are always there, right? And `12563` and `5640` can be any numbers?

Comment: yes i have 20170112 and 00000000ESPECE for every line. i just need to copy the number before 20170112 and replace it with the number before 00000000ESPECE @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `20170112` and `00000000ESPECE` are static and are always there and `12563` and `5640` can be any numbers.

Use a regex replace:

*Find What*: `\b(\d+)(\h+20170112\h+.*?)\b\d+(\h+00000000ESPECE)$`
*Replace With*: `$1$2$1$3`

**Details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (`$1` in the replacement) capturing one or more digits
- `(\h+20170112\h+.*?)` - Group 2 (`$2`) capturing 1+ horizontal whitespaces (`\h+`), `20170112`, 1+ horizontal whitespaces, and then any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible (`.*?`)
- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `\d+` -  1+ digits
- `(\h+00000000ESPECE)$` - Group 3 (`$3`) capturing 1+ hor. whitespaces and `00000000ESPECE` string that is at the end of the line (`$`).

See the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed explanation. this works :)

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `((\d+) 20170112\b.+?)\d+( 00000000ESPECE)`
- Replace with: `$1$2$3`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: This will perform find and replace if the numbers are found before `201701121112243456`, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew:You're right, I've added a word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly,if you do ctrl+f, there's a replace option.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ has a replace command.

If you need to replace only those, that have 2017 01 12 prior, then replace "2017 01 12 5640" with "2017 01 12 12563"

In a similar fashion you can include other static data if needed in search/replace conditions.

Comment: i don't think this will work. i have multiple lines of data that has 20170112 and 00000000ESPECE for every line. I just need to replace the number before 00000000ESPECE with the number before 20170112